# Limited selection in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, checkboxlist, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedBoxList an I want to limit the selection (checked) that you can select, for exapmle only 2 of 10 items in the Box. There are not really 10, it could also be 13 etc.

I tried already with this code, but here I can select only one Item (I want select more than one Item but not all).

```
    private void checkedListBox_ListOfCars_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox_ListOfCars.Items.Count; ++ix)
            {
                if (e.Index != ix) checkedListBox_ListOfCars.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you set CheckedListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple

Comment: @JunGuo Where I have to set it?

Comment: You're using winform, right? You can set it in the property page of the UI designer or in code.

Comment: @JunGuo Can't set it, the SelectionMode now is set on "One"! And yes I'm using winform in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a variable for the form like

```
int checkedItemsLimit = 2; // As you wrote in your question. This number is just an example.
```

Every time when something is checked at the ItemCheck event you can check if the numbers of checked items in the `checkListBox_ListOfCars` is equal to `checkedItemsLimit`. If this is present then unchecked the last checked. The code will look like that:

```
 private void checkedListBox_ListOfCars_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
     {
         if (checkedListBox_ListOfCars.CheckedItems.Count == checkedItemsLimit) 
         {
             e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
         }    
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ah... now it works. 2 hours ago it didn't worked, I don't know why! But thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!